# Error when injecting doctrine and custom service

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a problem with dependencies injections in Symfony3:

This is my services.yml

```
some_service:
    class: StagingBundle\Service\SomeService
    arguments: ['@doctrine']
    arguments: ['@test.other_service']
```

This is the constructor of SomeService.php

```
public function __construct($doctrine, SomeService $someService)
{
    $this->doctrine=$doctrine;
    $this->someService=$someService; 
}
```

When running my console command I get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to stagingBundle\Service\SomeService::__construct() must be an instance of StagingBundle\Service\OtherService, none given, called in /var/www/projects/myApp/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1141 and defined
```

Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"arguments" is an array and can only be there once, so it should look like this

```
some_service:
    class: StagingBundle\Service\SomeService
    arguments: ['@doctrine', '@test.other_service']
```